# Disabled context menu won't disappear after rightclick

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, tabcontrol

I have a `ContextMenu` as part of a `TabControl` such as:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl">
    <TabControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu" IsEnabled="False" StaysOpen="True">
            <MenuItem Header="Item1"></MenuItem>
            ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </TabControl.ContextMenu>
</TabControl>
```

As you can see, the menu is disabled. It will be enabled later in the program, for now however, it should remain in its disabled state. The problem is, when I right-click the `TabControl` and the disabled menu shows, it simply stays where it was first opened, no other right-click will move it, nor will a left-click somewhere make it disappear.

The only way to get rid of it, would be either by enabling it and then right/left-clicking, or by using `MyContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed/Hidden;`

I tried setting the `StaysOpen`-property to `False`. Then the menu will open once in its disabled state. After left-clicking disappear and then not appear again even if it gets enabled.

The only way around it could be changing the `StaysOpen`-property along with the `IsEnabled`-property, but it is a bit weird that the menu opens exactly once in its disabled state and then not anymore.

I hope anybody could explain to me, why exactly a disabled menu won't close and the property `StaysOpen` at false makes it open exactly once, because it seems like a weird behaviour to me.

Comment: Instead of disabling the `ContextMenu` try setting to null. What's the use of showing the disable context menu?

Comment: When I set it to null, it is just "gone" isn't it? I define the menu in the WPF code, because it is much simpler and don't need it until a certain point in the program. Imagine I have certain items within one tab of the `TabControl` and want to only enable the menu for certain items but at the start of the program, there are no items in any tab.

Comment: Having the same problem I found the following workaround:
instead of setting `contextMenu.IsEnabled = false` set all Items in contextMenu.Items collection `IsEnabled` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behaviour of context menu items is quite strange - what you've described is in .Net 4.0 and if you target yor app to .Net 3.5 for instance you will notice the opposite behaviour - you can't make the menu stay opened if the single item is disabled, it just disappears immediately after it shows on right click.

However I think the preferrable way to manage the enabled state of a context menu item (and also the OnClick action it should do) is by a `Command`.

First you should specify a datacontext for your view, let's say it is the class `ViewModel.cs`. Then create a command by implementing the `ICommand` interface, something like this:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
```

And then you have a `CanExecute` method which does exactly what it's name says - decides if the command can be executed or not. And the enabled state of the menu item also depends on the return value of this method. So you can keep it returning `false` as long as you need in and the menu will behave correctly and the menu item will be disabled. Then when you want you can make it return `true` (by some logic in the method itself) and you'll have again a properly working context menu with enabled menu item.

If you want to disable the entire menu, use the same approach but for the menu.

And if you need to make all the items in the menu disabled (which I think is different from the entire menu), then you can use something like this:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl" Background="Green">
            <TabControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu"  StaysOpen="True" ItemsSource="{Binding  Items}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}"  IsEnabled="False" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TabControl.ContextMenu>
        </TabControl>
```

Here your `ItemsSource` (`Items`) is for instance `List<MenuItem>`, and `MenuItem` itselw would be your Model (thinking in MVVM) for each of your menu items, which should have property `Header` that contains the header you want to see in each menu item. Instead of setting the `IsEnabled` to `false` as in my dummy example, you can bind it to a property in order to have control on when it must be true and false.

Comment: I hope you are realising that I am not disabling an item but the entire menu. Because I do occasionally disable items simply by setting the `IsEnabled`-Property to false and that works perfectly.

Comment: OK, use the same approach for the menu then :)